# PHP - Getting Content From External URL

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that would get the contents between the div tags

```
<div class="bio">

    <label>Bio:</label>

    <div class="value">[This Is The Content I'm Trying To Get]</div>

</div>
```

This is the URL I'm trying to get the contents from:

https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamertag=EMT%20PoRsChE

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) and [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
// if the below line does not work, you will need to use CURL or similar.
$theHtmlToParse = file_get_contents('http://url.to/page.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($theHtmlToParse);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@class='bio']/div[@class='value']");
// We now have an array of elements, or null
if ($elements !== null)
{
    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {
        echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {
          echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you enough to go on :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is actually possible.

You might use something like [visionmedia/php-selector](https://github.com/visionmedia/php-selector) to get the content of .value
and [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org) or some curl to get the source before, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

well, this can be done using `file_get_contents()` function.
Simply pass the `url` of the webpage into this `function` and then create an `object` of it.
Navigate through the object using`->` as required.